# How to update only one property of model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm working on user consents. In my request I have these properties:

```
$newsLetters (bool|nullable),
$sms (bool|nullable),
$billEmail (bool|nullable),
```

I need update only one. So I need to find one which is not null and update it, if in my request is more than one properties with bool values i need to throw exception.

How can I achieve this?

My request extends spatie/laravel-data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Your request does not say which attribute should be updated?

Comment: Making use of appropriate `input` elements in your `form` will remove the requirement for `null` checks. These might be `radio` (for single options) or `checkbox` (for multiple options) elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why would you handle something like this on the backend (you can use radio button for this and always send only one value), you can use validation for requests or something like this:

```
$newsLetters = null;
$sms = true;
$billEmail = null;
$values = [$newsLetters, $sms, $billEmail];
$filter = sizeof(array_filter($values, function($el) { return $el === null;})) < 2;
if($filter) {
  //return exception or whatever
} else {
  //update values
}
```